# xcode UILabel Text fits in storyboard but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I've created a custom cell in tableview and have added some labels to it. On setting constant text in the storyboard for each label, the text fully fits inside the labels properly (the size of each view is set to iPhone 5.5 inch). But as soon as I run the application on iPhone 6 (5.5 inch), the table cell generated does not fit the text inside the label properly and shows incomplete text ending with ellipsis. If the text fits properly in the label in Storyboard, why isn't it fitting properly in the device even if the screen sizes for both the cases is same? How to fix this problem?

EDIT: I've also added the lines in my code to automatically fit the text in the labels:

```
label.numberOfLines = 1
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.sizeToFit()
```

But it still doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What the OS version of your devices? As I know, different OS use different font.

Comment: OS version is iOS 8.2

Comment: No idea for your question. Maybe you can set autoshrink property of your label to workaround this problem.

Comment: Are you use autolayouts inside your cell? Or may be you set font for cell's label in code and this font is bigger then default in storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I've used autoLayouts inside the cell and the font for cell's label is much smaller than default font

Comment: @HarrisonXi, I tried everything with the autoshrink property. still not working

Comment: Please don't tag Swift related questions with the objective-c tag

Comment: sorry, but i will :P

Answer (score 1):

For me the below code works with every label that I use. This resizes the label according to the content description.

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.sizeToFit()
```

I hope this helps you in your custom cell too.

Answer (score 0):

call the below lines once you set the values for your label

```
self.yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
self.yourLabel.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
label.sizeToFit()
```

This setup you UILabel best

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Interface Builder.  Click your label and on the right inspector tab find Autoshrink.  Change that to Minimum Font Size and select what the minimum size you would like your font to be (I would suggest 12).  I know you said that you have tried using Autoshrink, but this works. No need to put label.sizeToFit()